# How do I create a PKCS12 self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, pkcs#12

How can I create this file?

If this functionality isn't built into Windows somewhere, I would prefer to work with C#.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770233/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-generate-an-x509-certificate-using-only-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232669/c-sharp-certificate-generation-framework . And no, it's not called "SSL certificate" and it has no relation to SSL. It's X.509 certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl` will do it for you.  Take a look at this FAQ https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self